# how to install open-library on ubuntu?

Tags: python, ubuntu, installation

i want to install openlibrary in my ubuntu system and i followed the instruction from the below  link http://openlibrary.org/dev/docs/setup

```
$ ./scripts/openlibrary-server openlibrary.yml
```

while i am using the above command it shows `infogami module not found` error message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to install 'infogami'. See [here](http://infogami.org/InstallGuide?v=12)

Comment: but why the above instruction not found in installation guide?

Comment: File a bug then? but usually certain things are assumed.